# sports VS. sporting

Tags: vocabulary

**Sports shoes
 / Sports car**

a.Television shows sporting events.

b.Television shows sports events.

Having taken into account the bold parts, it would be appreciated if somebody possibly explain what is the different between a and b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are cases where you can only use "sports" (*sports car*) or only "sporting" (*sporting chance*), in your example I cannot think of any difference in the two phrasings.

To back this up, I found [Ofcom](http://stakeholders.ofcom.org.uk/broadcasting/broadcast-codes/code-sports-events/) (UK broadcasting regulator) using both *sports events* and *sporting events* apparently interchangeably in official documents.

I can think of some related terms where "sports" would be definitely be better than "sporting":

- sports channel
- sports coverage
- sports reporter

Comment: So, which one, as a native speaker, would you rather use? sports shoes or sporting shoes

Comment: "sports shoes", although I'm more likely to use sneakers/trainers generically or "running shoes"/"basketball shoes"/etc to be specific.